Why is "dies" (day) masculine in Vulgate in Lucas 22:1, but feminine in Lucas 22:7?
In Lucas 22:1:

Appropinquabat autem dies festus azymorum, qui dicitur Pascha.

In Lucas 22:7:

Venit autem dies azymorum, in qua necesse erat occidi pascha.

I know "dies" can be both masculine and feminine depending on the context, but the context in those two sentences seems to be the same. So, why is "dies" once treated as masculine and once as feminine?

The compound term dies festus is masculine by convention. This is in contravention to the usual rule of thumb that a calendar dies is feminine while a period of daylight dies is masculine.
A search on dies festus turns up many hits in classical literature, all of them clearly masculine. Dies festa not so much. I cannot explain why this was so, but it clearly was so. I can understand why Jerome might be reluctant to violate such a widespread and ancient convention.

In the other order, though, we can find "festa dies", though seemingly only in poetry (where the ending -a is convenient for accompanying the short initial syllable of dies).

@Asteroides Cool! That's a lot of hits.  I'll have to rethink my answer. Although I doubt Jerome had much concern for metrical considerations. He was more likely trying to translate ἑορτὴ with a different phrase than ἡμέρα.
